# Unable to capture http request in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I am working in wireshark. I am monitoring the wifi traffic on the same network. We have 6 pc's there and one machine was installed on wireshark to  capture wifi traffic. I got my team mates Ip address in the endpoint list.  My machine have installed wiresahrk. whenever they ping to my machine. my machine ip : 192.168.1.214. and others are: 192.168.1.31, 164,188,242. and they ping a request to my m/c I can capture that request.
And if 192.168.1.188 machine send a http request to a local server to other ip like 164, 31 . I couldn't capture that http request. Its hows only mdns protocol.. here is the screenshot..

Why I can't capture the http request ? Why other team mates IP (188-->164.31) was not capture ?  Anyone please help me

I am working in ubuntu machine.

My router type is : `Belkin Surf N150 Wireless Modem Router, F9J1001 v1.`

```
root@naveen-Inspiron-3542:/home/naveen# airmon-ng start wlp6s0


Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!
-e 
PID Name
1114    NetworkManager
1117    avahi-daemon
1144    avahi-daemon
1311    wpa_supplicant
7662    dhclient
Process with PID 7662 (dhclient) is running on interface wlp6s0
Process with PID 8073 (dumpcap) is running on interface wlp6s0


Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlp6s0      Atheros     ath9k - [phy0]
                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

When I click on mon0 interface. I got the 802.11 management frames..
[image]

But my question is I can't capture the http request ?

Comment: You _do_ realize that the Wi-Fi data payloads are encrypted, don't you? How do you intend to read the encrypted payload where your HTTP data would be located?

Comment: @RonMaupin  yes I understand that the wifi data payloads are encrypted.  I don't know how to read

Comment: @RonMaupin please help me what should I do ?

Comment: You are not supposed to read the encrypted data, that is the point. Questions about bypassing network security or policies are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: @RonMaupin  where should I ask ? infoemation security right ?

Comment: You could try, but I don't think there is an SE site that will help you hack a network.

Comment: We are network engineers, and our job is to protect the network. We will not help you break the network security. For all I know, you are a user on one of my networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason is that you (and all the other hosts) are connected to a network switch.  The switch only forwards packets to the port where the destination host is.  Since you are not the destination, you don't see the packet.  Broadcast packets are forwarded out all ports, and that is what you are seeing in Wireshark.

If you have a Cisco switch, you can configure a span port to forward all traffic on the switch.

Comment: Not switch. we are connected in a router. model : Belkin Surf N150 Wireless Modem Router, F9J1001 v1

Comment: The router has a 4-port switch built into it.

Comment: Also, your wireless driver is likely in infrastructure mode, not monitor mode.

Comment: Are you seeing 802.11 management frames?  If not, then you are not in monitor mode.

Comment: I'm not an expert at Ubuntu, but I know that if you are in monitor mode, you should see all WiFi frames, including management frames. If you don't it's because your driver is abstracting Wi-fi to make it look like Ethernet.

Comment: But can you see management frames like beacons, probes, etc?

Comment: why I can't capture the http request from other two team mates send request each other ?

Comment: He just wanted to break the encryption, and he got sarcastic when I told him we wouldn't help.